# Json Schema minimum validator but for string

Tags: python-3.x, regex, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

using:

```
from jsonschema import validate
import jsonschema
```

I am trying to validate a minimum of 4096 with no upper bound on a string using json schema. I see regex pattern matching may be an option but unsure of how to do this with no upper bound.

```
json_data = {"value": "4096"}

# what i would like to do
json_schema = {"type": "string", "minimum": 4096}
try:
    validate(json_data, schema=json_schema)
    return True
except jsonschema.ValidationError:
    return False
```

Really appreciate any input. Please comment if other info is needed.  Thank you.

Comment: This question has enough information to give an answer. The question is regarding the use of JSON Schema. There is a clear correct answer here given the above question. I'm confused as to why this was closed, and I now can't answer. (Can any of those who voted to close please explain?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should enter your value as `int` instead of `string`.
Then you're checking the schema of your whole json object, from which `value` is a key/property:

```
from jsonschema import validate
import jsonschema

json_data = {"value": 4096}

json_schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "value": {
            "type": "number",
            "minimum": 4096
        }
    }
}
try:
    validate(json_data, schema=json_schema)
    print(True)
except jsonschema.ValidationError:
    print(False)
```

Try the above code with values < 4096 and >= 4096

EDIT: if changing the type of value is not an option, you can still use regex (in my opinion far uglier):

```
json_schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "value": {
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": "^\d{5,}|[5-9]\d{3}|4[1-9]\d\d|409[6-9]$"
        }
    }
}
```

This supposes your string has no leading zeroes and no kind of separators (`,`, `.`...). We match the following:

- `\d{5,}`: 5 or more digits (>= 10000)
- `[5-9]\d{3}`: 5 to 9 followed by 3 digits (5000-9999)
- `4[1-9]\d\d`: 4100 to 4999
- `409[6-9]`: 4096 to 4099